# How Can I resize img in Bootstrap carousel?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to build a website which is integrated in WordPress. My problem is the carousel's image doesn't sizing in carousel divs. How can I fix it?

HTML source

```
  <div class="item">
    <img src="http://i.hizliresim.com/z34va9.jpg" alt="Chania" width="460" height="345">
  </div>

<!-- Left and right controls -->
<a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
  <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
</a>
<a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
  <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
</a>
```

CSS source

```
.carousel-inner > .item > img,
    .carousel-inner > .item > a > img {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 533px;
```

}

Comment: are you sure that you're inserting the link to your CSS after the links to the bootstrap? Also, make sure you try to make your selectors as specific as possible.

Comment: Onur, `margin:533px` will apply this margin on all 4 margins.  I am pretty sure that is your real problem.

Answer (score 0):

`object: fit;` added to `img` worked for me. As I wanted my carousel to fill the whole page I've also used `height: 100vh; width: auto;`, but in your case it should be `width: 100%; height: auto;`.

P.S. I know it used to be asked one year ago, but might someone else would look for a solution.